# Integrate AWS API Gateway SDK into Angular 2 latest version

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-api-gateway

Kindly suggest the best possible way to integrate AWS API Gateway exported Javascript SDK  into Angular 2 latest Stable release ...

Such that the context change from angular 2 to SDK and back to Angular 2 shall not be a problem ...

I wish to avoid CORS issue's by using the SDK generated by the API Gateway

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to wrap the SDK, so that in response promises you can trigger the necessary Angular state update. Then make requests via the wrapper instead of directly through the generated SDK.

Comment: Thanx for the reply - this is something which I am already doing... What I wanna know is 1. is there a common pitfall to avoid, 2. Best Practise, 3. Solve the CORS preflight request in angular 2 using api sdk.  I would really appreciate it - if someone posts a Code Sample as well.